# AddThis data_track_addressbar not working in IE9, IE8, IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9, addthis

AddThis's url tracking doesn't seem to work for me in the browsers listed above. The tracking hash doesn't appear in the url. I've tried putting the AddThis code at the bottom of the body tag and in the head but it doesn't seem to affect things.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};
  </script>
  <script src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-523b5eb401d90168"></script>
</head>

<body><div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" >
  <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like share-fb" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_tweet share-tw"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone share-gp" g:plusone:size="medium"></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our address bar tracking uses the window.history HTML5 API that is only supported in Internet Explorer 10 and higher. [Details and example code are available here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Comment: Is this documented on AddThis.com and I just missed it?

Comment: Yep, it's documented here: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381254-address-bar-sharing-analytics#supported-browsers